# Метод поиска 3х минимумов в целочисленном ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java

Как написать такой метод, при том, что минимумы не должны повторяться?

Найти первый минимум проблемы не составляет, а вот с остальными что-то не клеится.

Comment: А изменять массив можно? Если можно, то почему бы не отсортировать массив и взять первые различные три элемента?

Comment: Сортировать можно, только без .sort();

Comment: а почему это без `.sort()`? без сортировки вообще можно после нахождения первого минимума, удалить все числа, равные ему из массива, и снова найти минимум. Далее удалить все числа втоого минимума, и найти третий

Comment: Потому что с .sort() слишком просто, я бы хотел понять для себя алгоритм выполнения такой задачи на более низком уровне.

Comment: Реализуй тогда метод сортировки. Допустим, quicksort

Comment: можно трижды циклом пройтись по массиву, записывать минимальное значение в очередную переменную и сравнивать её в последующих циклах с предыдущими записанными значениями. Вопрос только такой, найти три минимальных элемента или три минимальных значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой задачи хороша очередь с приоритетом:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> leastDistinctN(
        Collection<T> input, int n) {
    assert n > 0;
    PriorityQueue<T> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (T t : input) {
        if (pq.size() < n) {
            if (!pq.contains(t))
                pq.add(t);
        } else if (pq.peek().compareTo(t) > 0 && !pq.contains(t)) {
            pq.poll();
            pq.add(t);
        }
    }
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(pq);
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
System.out.println(leastDistinctN(Arrays.asList(5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 10, 8), 3)); // [0, 1, 3]
```

Здесь мы в очереди в каждый момент храним не больше `n` разных минимальных чисел. Если нашли число меньше существующих, то удаляем наибольшее на текущий момент и добавляем новое. В конце копируем очередь в массив и сортируем. Очередь с приоритетом — очень классная и эффективная структура данных. Часто для подобных операций используют какой-нибудь развесистый `TreeSet`, что вообще неоправданно. Не забывайте про очередь с приоритетом.

Если `n` сильно меньше размера коллекции, это будет заметно быстрее, чем сортировать всю коллекцию. Например, для коллекции из миллиона случайных элементов и `n = 3` моя версия работает в 100 раз быстрее, чем сортировка.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] loc = {25, 11, 250,5, 45,8,10,45,31,123,489};
        for(int i = 0; i < loc.length; i ++) {
            for (int j = loc.length-1; j >i ; j--) {
                if (loc[j] < loc[j - 1]) {
                    int temp = loc[j];
                    loc[j] = loc[j - 1];
                    loc[j - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
            System.out.println(loc[i]);
        }
    }
```

вот код на java

Comment: А теперь добавьте в ваш массив два одинаковых минимума и еще раз прочитайте вопрос. PS. сортировка пузырьков не самая быстрая.

Comment: Это в общем-то массив, а в задаче я интересовался по поводу коллекции ArrayList. Сейчас поправлю и проверю работает ли.

Comment: Форматирование поправил, но вот <br/> пожалуйста сами удалите ))

Answer (score 2):

Вот накидал с достаточно подробными, для того чтобы разобраться самому, комментариями программу, которая работает без сортировки за линейное время. Идея в том, чтобы проходя однократно по массиву поддерживать акутальными *текущие* три минимальные числа, обновляя их с учетом каждого последующего элемента массива. Это решение легко расширяется на поиск любого фиксированного числа N минимальных элементов, не только трех.

P.S. Для `ArrayList` с алгоритмической точки зрения все делается точно так же. Я написал, как мне проще и быстрее, чтобы объяснить суть решения, а не конкретную техническую реализацию.

```
class Test {

  // Здесь будут храниться наши три минимальные числа.
  static int min[] = {Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE};

  // Обновляем массив `min` имея новое число-кандидат в минимум.
  static void updateMin(int x) {
    // Перебираем текущие минимальные числа.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      if (x < min[i]) {
        // Новое число меньше рассматриваемого из `min`.

        // Сдвигаем текущее и последующие числа, чтобы освободить место
        // для нового.
        for (int j = 2; j > i; --j)
          min[j] = min[j - 1];

        // Вставляем новое число на полагающееся ему место.
        min[i] = x;

        // Дело сделано.
        return;
      } else if (x == min[i]) {
        // Новое число равно рассматриваемому из `min`.

        // Заканчиваем, т.к. такое число уже есть среди минимальных.
        return;
      }

      // Иначе переходим к следующему числу из `min`
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int loc[] = {25, 11, 250, 5, 45, 8, 10, 45, 31, 123, 489};

    // Находим три минимальных числа.
    for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; ++i)
      updateMin(loc[i]);

    // Выводим их
    // (проверка на MAX_VALUE на случай, если минимальных чисел окажется
    //  меньше трех).
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && min[i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i)
      System.out.println(min[i]);
  }
}
```